# hive 3.0.0 want to convert timestamp to string with a mask

Tags: hive, timestamp, hiveql, to-char

I have to revert a date conversion
At the beginning it was

```
CAST(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t0.date_creation , 'yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss')) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Now I'm looking on how to convert a timestamp to the format `'yyyyMMdd'T'hhmmss'`

the syntax `CAST(date_creation as string format 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss')`  is not working

Answer (score 1):

Use `date_format` function:

```
select current_timestamp, date_format(current_timestamp,"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss") as result;
```

Returns:

```
2020-10-09 15:03:36.584       20201009T150336
```

Read about format here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I found also this from_unixtime(cast (date_creation as bigint),'yyyyMMdd\'T\'hhmmss') but your solution is more elegant

Comment: @Jeannot77680 I hope you clearly understand the difference between `hh` and `HH` format. Check it if you did not the same yet. Refer SimpleDateFormat class Java docs. `hh` is 01-12 date format. `HH` is 00-23.  `hh` alone without AM/PM makes no sense

Comment: you're right, the mask was wrong at the beginning and I did wrong too. Bravo